# How do I compute a variable in JavaScript if and only if it is used?

Tags: javascript, variables

This is what I'm doing right now.

```
var foo = function() {
  var x = someComplicatedComputationThatMayTakeMoreTime();
  this.foo = function() { return x; };
  return x;
}
```

It works but only if foo is called as a function like so

```
foo();
```

But what if I want to call it as a normal variable with a value? I could modify the code to be

```
var foo = function() {
  var x = someComplicatedComputationThatMayTakeMoreTime();
  this.foo = x;
  return x;
}
```

That would allow me to only call it once as a function and after that as a regular variable. But it's still not what I want. Plus it gets complicated if it accidentally gets called as a function again, returning an error.

Is this even possible in JavaScript?

BTW, this is for a Chrome/Firefox extension, so IE compatibility does not matter.

Ended up using toString because getters don't allow me to redefine the whole attribute, a function must be associated with it. And toString has cleaner syntax.

Comment: There's two problems with your use of `this.foo`: 1.) `this` refers to the top-level object (`window`) if called as `foo()`, and 2.) If you assign `foo` to a variable and call that variable many times, `foo` will be updated on every call because that variable isn't getting changed.

Comment: This was only an example, most of these are defined inside objects so this refers to the object. And I checked with a simple alert() function to see if it was getting called many times or just once and it's the value is only computed once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using toString?

```
var foo = function() {
  function someComplicatedComputationThatMayTakeMoreTime() {
        //your calculations
  }
  return {
      toString: function() { 
           return someComplicatedComputationThatMayTakeMoreTime(); 
      }
  }
}
```

More about [Object-to-Primitive Conversions in JavaScript](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript)

*EDIT* based on comment. Use a singleton (I think it's called):

```
myObject.prop = (function(){ 
                  function someComplicatedComputationThatMayTakeMoreTime() {
                   //your calculations
                  }
                  return { 
                    toString: function() { 
                     return someComplicatedComputationThatMayTakeMoreTime(); 
                    } 
                  } 
                })()
```

Comment: Wow this works because toString is only called if the variable is used. Thanks.

Comment: If `foo` is accessed twice, then wouldn't the complicated calculation be done twice?

Comment: It would. If you don't want that, you should add an extra property (say: result) in the returned Object. Now add a check to toString: if the result property has no value, do the calculation (in toString), assign its result to the property and return it. If it has a value, return that value.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it works. :D

var foo = {
  toString: function() {
    return foo = someComplicatedComputationThatMayTakeMoreTime(); ;
  }
}

The only problem with this right now is if I want to do this with an object's property, I can't access other properties without knowing the name of the object, I was previously using "this.otherproperty". Not that big of a deal, but I'm always looking to make things flexible so I'm using __defineGetter__() for those.

Comment: @LLer: see the edited answer, but maybe you mean something else?

Comment: IMO, this is a very hairy way of going about things. This will only work in cases where the object is implicitly convereted into a string.

Answer (score 4):

If only Internet Explorer didn't exist, you could use getters and setters as described by John Resig in this blog article:

- [John Resig: JavaScript Getters and Setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/#postcomment)

> ... They allow you to bind special functions to an object that look like normal object properties, but actually execute hidden functions instead.

Comment: Apparently I discover that they are partially supported in IE8, but using different syntax: http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/28/getters-and-setters-with-javascript-code-samples-and-demos/. IE8 is using the `Object.defineProperty` method, which should become the ECMAScript standard.

Answer (score 3):

Using a function is your best option *for now*, however the new JavaScript standard (ECMAScript 5th Ed.) which is being [implemented now](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table) by all major browser vendors, gives you a method to create *accessor properties*, where you can define a property with a `get` and `set` functions that will be internally called, without worrying to treat this properties as functions, e.g.:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
  get: function () { // getter logic
    return 'foo!';
  },
  set: function (value) {
    // setter logic
  }
});

obj.foo; // "foo!", no function call
```

This new standard will take some time to be implemented for all browsers, (the IE9 preview version *really* disappointed me), and I wouldn't recommend you to use it for production, unless you have total control on the environment where your application will be used.

Comment: Yes, it's the ES5 standard syntax, from the [TC39 committee](http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC39.htm)

Comment: I know, I just think the syntax is absolutely horrible.

Comment: Yes it's kinda ugly, but this syntax was selected very carefully, as you can see no new grammar has been defined, the method receives a plain old object, introducing new grammar would have made the adoption of the new standard slower, giving more compatibility issues...

Answer (score 2):

What I think you want is a lazily instantiated variable, which can be implemented like this.

```
var myProperty = null;
function getMyProperty() {
    return (myProperty = myProperty ||  builder());
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to use myProperty variable without having to worry about calling getMyProperty().

Comment: That's effectively what he has now (although I like yours better).

Comment: @LLer - Unfortunately, JavaScript does not support this. Why don't you try Haskell? :)

Comment: After experimenting with an edit of this, I've found something that I think works.

Answer (score 2):

This is not practical on the web because IE does not support it, but you can look at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/defineGetter for examples how to do this.

There are a couple ways to do it, here is one example:

```
var data = {};
data.__defineGetter__("prop",
                      (function () {
                           var value = null;
                           return function () {
                             if (null == value) {
                               value = getYourValueHere();
                             }
                             return value;
                           };
                        })());
```

and now you can use it like:

```
var a = data.prop;
var b = data.prop;
```

Comment: Fortunately this is for a Chrome/Firefox extension, so IE does not matter. :)

Comment: In that case it will work perfectly, I have used it in a Firefox extension too. Check out the docs, there is a friendlier syntax than the one I showed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a variation on [ChaosPandion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703304/how-do-i-compute-a-variable-in-javascript-if-and-only-if-it-is-used/2703319#2703319), but with a closure.

```
var myProperty = (function () {
  var innerProperty = null;
  return function() {
    return (innerProperty = innerProperty ||  someComplicatedComputationThatMayTakeMoreTime());
  };
})();
```

and then use `myProperty()` every time you need to access the variable.

Comment: Now wouldn't it be nice if you could just do `lazy myProperty = builder();`?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a JavaScript getter. From the [Apple JavaScript Coding Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/ScriptingAutomation/Conceptual/JSCodingGuide/OOJavaScript/OOJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006539-DontLinkElementID_17):

```
myObject.__defineGetter__( "myGetter", function() { return this.myVariable; } );
var someVariable = myObject.myGetter;
```

See John Resig's post, [JavaScript Getters and Setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/), and the [Defining Getters and Setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Defining_Getters_and_Setters)  page  at the [Mozilla Developer Centre](http://developer.mozilla.org/En) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would use explicit lazy evaluation. Here's my implementation of it based on Scheme's take:

```
var delay, lazy, force, promise, promiseForced, promiseRunning;

(function () {

  var getValue = function () {
    return this.value;
  };

  var RUNNING = {};

  var DelayThunk = function (nullaryFunc) {
    this.value = nullaryFunc;
  };
  DelayThunk.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "[object Promise]";
  };
  DelayThunk.prototype.force = function () {
    if (promiseRunning (this)) {
      throw new Error ("Circular forcing of a promise.");
    }
    var nullaryFunc = this.value;
    this.value = RUNNING;
    this.value = nullaryFunc ();
    this.force = getValue;
    return this.value;
  };

  var LazyThunk = function (nullaryFunc) {
    DelayThunk.call (this, nullaryFunc);
  };
  LazyThunk.prototype = new DelayThunk (null);
  LazyThunk.prototype.constructor = LazyThunk;
  LazyThunk.prototype.force = function () {
    var result = DelayThunk.prototype.force.call (this);
    while (result instanceof LazyThunk) {
      result = DelayThunk.prototype.force.call (result);
    }
    return force (result);
  };

  delay = function (nullaryFunc) {
    return new DelayThunk (nullaryFunc);
  };

  lazy = function (nullaryFunc) {
    return new LazyThunk (nullaryFunc);
  };

  force = function (expr) {
    if (promise (expr)) {
      return expr.force ();
    }
    return expr;
  };

  promise = function (expr) {
    return expr instanceof DelayThunk;
  };

  promiseForced = function (expr) {
    return expr.force === getValue || !promise (expr);
  };

  promiseRunning = function (expr) {
    return expr.value === RUNNING || !promise (expr);
  };

}) ();
```

Example Syntax:

```
var x = lazy (function () { return expression; });
var y = force (x);

var z = delay (function () { return expression; });
var w = force (z);
```

Note values are stored once evaluated, so repeated forcing will not do extra computations.

Example usage:

```
function makeThunk (x, y, z) {
  return lazy (function () {
    // lots of work done here
  });
}

var thunk = makeThunk (arg1, arg2, arg3);

if (condition) {
  output (force (thunk));
  output (force (thunk)); // no extra work done; no extra side effects either
}
```

Comment: The usage looks promising. Thanks. This is interesting, I'll try to understand it in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the javascript `Proxy` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for creating such functionality.

```
var object = {};
var handler = {

    resolvers: {},

    get ( target, property, proxy ) {

        if ( ! target.hasOwnProperty( property ) && this.resolvers.hasOwnProperty( property ) ) {
            // execute the getter for the property;
            target[ property ] = this.resolvers[ property ]();
        }
        return target[ property ];

    },

    set ( target, property, value, receiver ) {

        // if the value is function set as a resolver
        if ( typeof value === 'function' ) {
            this.resolvers[property] = value;
        // otherwise set value to target
        } else {
            target.property = value;
        }
    },

    has ( target, property, receiver ) {
        //true when proxy handler has either a resolver or target has a value;
        return this.resolvers.hasOwnProperty( property ) || target.hasOwnProperty( property );
    }

};

var lazyObject = new Proxy( object, handler );
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
'exampleField' in lazyObject; //returns false
lazyObject.exampleField = function(){ return 'my value' }; // add a resolver function
'exampleField' in lazyObject; //returns true
lazyObject.exampleField; //executes your resolver function and returns 'my value'
```

This example is to demonstrate the working. You can change after your needs.

Here is [a **fiddle** with a demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/odtuteqh/)